# Print repeating pattern

Tags: linux, bash, grep, regular-expression, duplicate

I have a marathon file from which I want to print the names of the runners, who have made multiple runs. Something like:

```
M, 2:08:58.0, John Lukas, USA, 1997-07-25, Paris, France

F, 2:15:04:0, Abebbe Boukari, KEN, 2000-10-01, London, UK
```

and so on

I have tried with uniq but it just doesn`t happen:

```
uniq -d marathon | grep "[[:alpha:]]\+[ ]\+[[:alpha:]]"
```

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: all runners who had participated more than once, because in the list there are such who repeat over time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another simple, alternative(for someone  who dont want/know `awk`) script will be:

```
#!/bin/bash
sort -t',' -k 3 marathon | cut -d',' -f 3 | uniq -d
```

if someone wants to print whole line instead of **just** names:

```
#!/bin/bash
sort -t',' -k 3 marathon | cut -d',' -f 3 | uniq -d | grep -f - marathon
```

in over scripts:

- `sort` takes third field to sort, using `,` as separator from `-t` option and 3rd field from `-k` option
- `cut` command just cuts out third field using `,` as separator
- `-d` option for `uniq` just prints duplicate lines, which is what the author of the question wanted - "Print repeating pattern"
- `-f` option takes input from pipe(i.e. names) and searches it in marathon file to give whole line instead of just names

Answer (score 3):

You have to sort using names first.

> Note: 'uniq' does not detect repeated lines unless they are adjacent.  You may  want
>          to  sort  the input first, or use `sort -u' without `uniq'.

You can use the `-t/-k` options, to sort these fields:

```
sort -t',' -k 3 marathon
```

that sort regarding the 3rd field with the comma as separator.

Then you can print only the 3rd column with awk, and then use the `uniq` command:

```
sort -t',' -k 3 marathon | awk -F, '{print $3}'|uniq -d
```

---

/!\ not tested

If you want to keep all the lines, you can use awk to save the number of times the name appear (`count[$3]++`); keep all the lines for the names (`lines[$3]=lines[$3]?lines[$3]+"\n"+$0:$0;`: if it's the first, store the lines, else append). At the end, if count number ≥ 2, print the lines for the names (`if(count[i]>1){ print lines[i]}`):

```
sort -t',' -k 3 marathon | awk -F, '{count[$3]++;lines[$3]=lines[$3]?lines[$3]+"\n"+$0:$0;}END{for (i in count){if(count[i]>1){ print lines[i]}}}'
```

Comment: how would look that if I want to preserve the whole lines(gender, time name, year) with the duplicates and is that possible with grep instead of awk?

Comment: @HighlightsFactory I made a script that satisfies your condition